# PySpark local unittest - py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.collectToPython

Tags: unit-testing, pyspark, databricks

I am doing some tests how to start with Spark unittesting. I have the following scenario.

Folder structure as follows:

```
src/
  transformers.py
tests/
   unit/
      test_transformers.py
```

The code in the transofomers.py file looks like this (very basic):

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def convert_sales_cent_to_euro(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    df = df.withColumn('sales_in_euro', F.round(F.col('sales')/100., 2))
    return df


def groupBy_sum(df:DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    df = df.groupBy('store').agg({'sales_in_euro':'sum'})
    return df
```

I only wrote a unit test for the convert_sales_cent_to_euro function yet. The test_transfomers.py looks like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import src.transformers as tr

def get_spark():
    spark = (SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]") \
                    .appName('unittest') \
                    .getOrCreate())
    return spark

def test_convert_sales_to_euro():
    spark = get_spark()
    input_schema = T.StructType([
                                    T.StructField('store', T.StringType(), True),
                                    T.StructField('sales', T.FloatType(), True),
                                ])
    input_data = [('Madrid', 10301.75),
                  ('London', 0.),
                  ('Paris', 103013.)]
    input_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=input_data, schema=input_schema)
    
    expected_schema = T.StructType([
                                    T.StructField('store', T.StringType(), True),
                                    T.StructField('sales', T.FloatType(), True),
                                    T.StructField('sales_in_euro', T.FloatType(), True),
                                ])
    expected_data = [('Madrid', 10301.75, 103.02),
                     ('London', 0., 0.),
                     ('Paris', 103013., 1030.13)]
    expected_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=expected_data, schema=expected_schema)

    transformed_df = tr.convert_sales_cent_to_euro(input_df)

    assert set(expected_df.columns) == set(transformed_df.columns)
    assert sorted(expected_df.collect()) == sorted(transformed_df.collect())
```

When I execute `python -m pytest tests/unit/`, I get **the following error**:

```
FAILED tests/unit/test_transformers.py::test_convert_sales_to_euro - py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.collectToPython.
```

I also get this warning (but not sure if it is related to it):

```
RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 112 from C header, got 124 from PyObject
    return f(*args, **kwds)
```

Anyone who knows what the problem is? I executes the script in Databricks, and there I didn't get a problem. So I assume it is related to my local spark session.

**Edit:** Full error below

```
================================================== FAILURES ================================================== 
_________________________________________ test_convert_sales_to_euro _________________________________________ 

    def test_convert_sales_to_euro():
        spark = get_spark()
        input_schema = T.StructType([
                                        T.StructField('store', T.StringType(), True),
                                        T.StructField('sales', T.FloatType(), True),
                                    ])
        input_data = [('Madrid', 10301.75),
                      ('London', 0.),
                      ('Paris', 103013.)]
        input_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=input_data, schema=input_schema)

        expected_schema = T.StructType([
                                        T.StructField('store', T.StringType(), True),
                                        T.StructField('sales', T.FloatType(), True),
                                        T.StructField('sales_in_euro', T.FloatType(), True),
                                    ])
        expected_data = [('Madrid', 10301.75, 103.02),
                         ('London', 0., 0.),
                         ('Paris', 103013., 1030.13)]
        expected_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=expected_data, schema=expected_schema)

        transformed_df = tr.convert_sales_cent_to_euro(input_df)

        assert set(expected_df.columns) == set(transformed_df.columns)
>       assert sorted(expected_df.collect()) == sorted(transformed_df.collect())

tests\unit\test_transformers.py:35:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  
..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:817: in collect
    sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322: in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py:190: in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  

answer = 'xro59', gateway_client = <py4j.clientserver.JavaClient object at 0x110512F0>, target_id = 'o53'      
name = 'collectToPython'

    def get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id=None, name=None):
        """Converts an answer received from the Java gateway into a Python object.

        For example, string representation of integers are converted to Python
        integer, string representation of objects are converted to JavaObject
        instances, etc.

        :param answer: the string returned by the Java gateway
        :param gateway_client: the gateway client used to communicate with the Java
            Gateway. Only necessary if the answer is a reference (e.g., object,
            list, map)
        :param target_id: the name of the object from which the answer comes from
            (e.g., *object1* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
        :param name: the name of the member from which the answer comes from
            (e.g., *hello* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
        """
        if is_error(answer)[0]:
            if len(answer) > 1:
                type = answer[1]
                value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
                if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
                    raise Py4JJavaError(
                        "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>                       format(target_id, ".", name), value)
E                   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.collectToPython.
E                   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (PC6607.dc.tess.elex.be executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:189)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:164)        
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)    
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
E                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
E                   Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
E                       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
E                       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:176)
E                       ... 29 more
E
E                   Driver stacktrace:
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
E                       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
E                       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
E                       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
E                       at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2249)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2268)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2293)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1021)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)      
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)      
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1020)
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:424)        
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectToPython$1(Dataset.scala:3688)
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3858)
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:510)
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3856)
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3856)
E                       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3685)
E                       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
E                       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
E                       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
E                       at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
E                       at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
E                       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
E                       at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
E                       at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
E                       at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)        
E                       at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
E                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
E                   Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:189)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:164)        
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)    
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
E                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
E                       ... 1 more
E                   Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
E                       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
E                       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
E                       at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:176)
E                       ... 29 more

..\..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:328: Py4JJavaError
-------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------- 
23/01/19 13:23:47 WARN Shell: Did not find winutils.exe: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
23/01/19 13:23:48 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/01/19 13:23:59 WARN SizeEstimator: Failed to check whether UseCompressedOops is set; assuming yes
23/01/19 13:24:09 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:189)   
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:176)   
        ... 29 more
23/01/19 13:24:09 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (PC6607.dc.tess.elex.be executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:189)   
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:176)   
        ... 29 more

23/01/19 13:24:09 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
-------------------------------------------- Captured stderr call -------------------------------------------- 
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from 
Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
============================================== warnings summary ============================================== 
tests/unit/test_transformers.py::test_convert_sales_to_euro
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Python3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 112 from C header, got 124 from PyObject
    return f(*args, **kwds)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
========================================== short test summary info =========================================== 
FAILED tests/unit/test_transformers.py::test_convert_sales_to_euro - py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.collectToPython.
======================================= 1 failed, 1 warning in 28.84s ========================================
```

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: @AlexOtt. Done, I added the full error.

Comment: @gamezone25 - Did you find solution? I am facing same issue when testing pytest locally